# How to automatically import the namespace of a class in VS Code?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I want to add the namespace of a php class automatically with a shortcut/extension in vscode, but I can't find how to do this.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models;


class Article {
}
```

Comment: How would VSC *know* the namespace…?

Comment: By the directory structure. I had a similar function in Sublime Text

Comment: It's not a free solution but you can by using resharper plugin https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Answer (score 65):

Use this handy [PHP Namespace Resolver](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MehediDracula.php-namespace-resolver) extension for **Visual Studio Code**.

**How to use:**

1. Right click on any class name and select ***Import Class*** to automatically import it's namespace at the top of the file
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> on Windows / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> on MacOS

[image: https://i.imgur.com/upEGtPa.gif]

Comment: how can i config vscode to connect to implementation of the interface? @arsalanramay

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi If you are using proper namespaces for all your interfaces and their implementations, you can just import the implementation class by clicking on the name of the Interface just like the above example.

Answer (score 44):

Another way is to

1. highlight the class by double click on the class name.
2. press `ctrl` + `space` keys and then from the list, the namespace of
   the specific class can be seen.
3. select the desired namespace from the list by up-down arrow keys
4. press the `Tab` key to import the namespace automatically at above
   the page.

Hope this helps,

Comment: thanks you so much, Your solution was the only way that worked for me

Comment: how can i config vscode to link my all interfaces tp my implementations ?

Comment: Using the built in system should probably be the accepted answer imo

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the namespace isn't showing in the list. Even though while highlighting the first option which pops up (which is the name of the class) it does show the class signature and namespace in a little preview box, but when clicking it, it just "replaces" my highlighted code with the class name that's already there.

Answer (score 4):

[PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) is the best extension I've ever used for this.

It provides both autocomplete and auto-import.

Comment: You are right, but it's important to say the auto-import is a premium feature.